# Magento 2 Commerce cloud database export

Tags: database, magento2.2.6, export, magento2-cloud, magento-2-commerce

I am new in magento commerce cloud. I need to setup the magento store in my local system. I have downloaded the files from the commerce git and it is working fine. But how can I access the database? I need to import the database to my local system. I have created the database backup using the below command.

> vendor/bin/ece-tools db-dump

How can I download it in to my local system? Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MSA has noted, you can ssh into the machine and use `ece-tools db-dump` and then rsync the database dump down locally.Here is the rsync command

```
 rsync -avzh <SSH URL>:/tmp/<BACKUP NAME> ./
```

Another option is to utilize the `magento-cloud` CLI utility.  You can download the CLI utility with these instructions:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/cloud/before/before-workspace-magento-prereqs.html#cloud-ssh-cli-cli-install

Once you have that installed you can create a dump like this:
`magento-cloud db:dump -p <PROJECT ID> -e <ENVIRONMENT NAME>`

The `magento-cloud CLI will also allow you to open up an SSH tunnel to the database so you could access it locally.

Comment: I have created the dump. Now I need to download it into my local system.

Comment: You just need to rsync it local.  Something like this should work:
`rsync -avzh <SSH URL>:/tmp/<BACKUP NAME> ./`

Comment: Yes, Now it is working. Thank you so much Billy Gilbert. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

db-dump (ece-tools; recommended)

You may dump your DB using the **ECE-Tools command**:

To update the ece-tools package:

On your local workstation, perform an update using Composer.

```
composer update magento/ece-tools
```

If you cannot update beyond ece-tools version 2002.0.8, follow the upgrade steps.

Add, commit, and push your code changes.

```
git add -A && git commit -m "Update magento/ece-tools" && git push origin <branch name>
```

After test validation, merge this branch to the Integration branch.

```
vendor/bin/ece-tools db-dump
```

This the recommended and the safest option.

Download Database

1. We recommend putting the application in maintenance mode before doing a database dump in Production environments.
2. The command creates an archive in your local project directory called **`dump-<timestamp>.sql.gz.`**
3. If an error occurs during the dump, the command deletes the dump file to conserve disk space. Review the logs for details (/var/log/cloud.log).

For more details refer https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003254334-Create-database-dump-on-Cloud

Comment: I have created the backup using this command vendor/bin/ece-tools db-dump. It creates the backup in /tmp folder. How can I download it into my local workstation

Comment: Check updated answer @jancy

Comment: Yes the command creates an archive dump-<timestamp>.sql.gz. in my  /tmp directory. Not in my project directory

Comment: mysqldump -u {user} -p {database} | gzip > {database}.sql.gz

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, it will  gives an error like this "Read-only file system. mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
". If I give var/ path then it will create the backup in var/ directory/

Answer (score 0):

What about the db:dump command?

```
Command: db:dump
Description: Create a local dump of the remote database
Usage:
 magento-cloud db:dump [--schema SCHEMA] [-f|--file FILE] [-d|--directory DIRECTORY] [-z|--gzip] [-t|--timestamp] [-o|--stdout] [--table TABLE] [--exclude-table EXCLUDE-TABLE] [--schema-only] [--charset CHARSET] [-p|--project PROJECT] [--host HOST] [-e|--environment ENVIRONMENT] [-A|--app APP] [-r|--relationship RELATIONSHIP] [-i|--identity-file IDENTITY-FILE]
Options:
      --schema=SCHEMA                The schema to dump. Omit to use the default schema (usually "main").
  -f, --file=FILE                    A custom filename for the dump
  -d, --directory=DIRECTORY          A custom directory for the dump
  -z, --gzip                         Compress the dump using gzip
  -t, --timestamp                    Add a timestamp to the dump filename
  -o, --stdout                       Output to STDOUT instead of a file
      --table=TABLE                  Table(s) to include (multiple values allowed)
      --exclude-table=EXCLUDE-TABLE  Table(s) to exclude (multiple values allowed)
      --schema-only                  Dump only schemas, no data
      --charset=CHARSET              The character set encoding for the dump
  -p, --project=PROJECT              The project ID or URL
      --host=HOST                    The project's API hostname
  -e, --environment=ENVIRONMENT      The environment ID
  -A, --app=APP                      The remote application name
  -r, --relationship=RELATIONSHIP    The service relationship to use
  -i, --identity-file=IDENTITY-FILE  An SSH identity (private key) to use
  -h, --help                         Display this help message
  -q, --quiet                        Do not output any message
  -V, --version                      Display this application version
  -y, --yes                          Answer "yes" to any yes/no questions; disable interaction
  -n, --no                           Answer "no" to any yes/no questions; disable interaction
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose               Increase the verbosity of messages

Examples:

 Create an SQL dump file:
   magento-cloud db:dump 

 Create a gzipped SQL dump file named "dump.sql.gz":
   magento-cloud db:dump --gzip -f dump.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import any **.sql.gz** file using following command :

zcat ./your_db_name.sql.gz | sed -e 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' | mysql -u root2 -p db_password