# Magento 2: How to dump database from Magento cloud

Tags: magento2, database, magento2-cloud, database-export

How to dump the database to local system from **Magento Cloud** server with Magento 2 Commerce.
I have only access to the ssh but that ssh user doesn't have write permission into the server. So by any how I need to download the database to the local system.

I have also tried to run the below command in my local system:

> mysqldump -h hostname -u username -p dbname > dbname.sql

Hostname I used same as ssh host because I found 127.0.0.1 as db host on `app/etc/env.php`. But unfortunately it doesn't help.

I have checked this [Magento 2 Commerce cloud database export](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279316/magento-2-commerce-cloud-database-export) but I dont know how to use this?

Is `ece-tools db-dump` already available in Magento cloud? Or we need to install it? If I need to install it then I cannot do this as there is no write permission is there in the server. I can only use git.

Is there any other way to do this Or How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Install magento-cloud cli

   - https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html
2. Get a project and environment with the magento-cloud cli
3. Run command to go into the current environment, dump the file, and then download it to your local computer

   - `magento-cloud db:dump`

Comment: This is very bad idea, as magento-cloud dump also exports the views with original owner, so access to most of tables will be non accessible. BTW Magento does not reccomend using it on a cloud see https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003254334-Create-database-dump-on-Cloud

Comment: Once you have the dump file you have to make sure to remove the definer:

zcat ${backupFilePath} | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/'

Comment: For my own personal script i use magerun to dump the db and also strip any sensitive data, then i download the dump from the server. ece-tools doesn't allow you to do that, neither does the magento-cloud tool.

Answer (score 2):

ece-tools is available in magneto 2 . 
You can just refer link https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/ece-tools-reference.html

Answer (score 2):

just install magento [cloud cli](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html) and then

```
magento-cloud db:dump
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Carlos Reynosa said, it worked.

While installing magento-cloud cli through git bash, I got the error saying

```
stdin is not a tty

curl: (23) Failed writing body (343 != 7113)
```

then I tried the following to install magento-cloud in local

```
$ curl -sS https://accounts.magento.cloud/cli/installer -o cli-installer.php

$ php cli-installer.php
```

2. Get into appropriate project and environment
3. Run the command `magento-cloud db:dump`